Experimental generalizations of some of Ramaré and Garnier's trigonometric identities for the Fibonacci numbers
I found, experimentally, a couple of neat generalizations of trigonometric identities for the Fibonacci numbers by Ramaré and Garnier:
$$
F_{2m+1}(x) = \prod_{k=1}^m \left( x^2 + 4 \cos^2 \left( \frac{k\pi}{2m+1} \right) \right)
$$
and
$$
\frac{F_{2m+2}(x)}{x} = \prod_{k=1}^m \left( x^2 + 4 \cos^2 \left( \frac{k\pi}{2m+2} \right) \right)
$$
where $F_{2m+1}(x)$ is the $(2m+1)$-th Fibonacci polynomial evaluated at $x$.
How might one go about proving them?
I've seen the methods used by Ramaré and Garnier to prove their less general identities, but they are way above my paygrade. Maybe they could be proved in a similar fashion.
Is there some easier way of proving these identities?

https://www.fq.math.ca/Papers1/46_47-1/Ramare_Garnier_11-08.pdf
